# How do I make bold text in body message?

Tags: html

How do I make text to be bold in body when sending email using swithmail?

tried this `<b>This text is bold</b>`

Comment: Did you specify "html"-Mail? In a "text"-Mail, there is no "bold". Also, what result did you get instead of what you expected?

Comment: when you send plain text its not possible I guess, when you send html use <strong> or css font-weight:bold

Comment: does this work? https://sourceforge.net/p/swithmail/wiki/markdown_syntax/#md_ex_text

Comment: @Raqha has the right idea: [RTM](https://sourceforge.net/p/swithmail/wiki/markdown_syntax/#md_ex_text)

Answer (score 0):

`$mail->IsHTML(true);` for your email to be in a HTML form and wrap your bold text inside a `<b></b>` tag

Comment: can you show an example, how do i for add HTML with swithmail code?

Comment: here's an example use it and just add the code I provided so you can send your emails with bold text.
https://swiftmailer.symfony.com/docs/introduction.html